# EntityFramework stored prrocedure with Npgsql

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, npgsql, ef-postgresql

this will be a silly question :

how to call a stored procedure with EntityFramework on a Postgresql database using npgsql as a data provider.

i have tried ExecuteFunction but it tells me that

```
The FunctionImport 'ClientFields' could not be found in the container 'BusinessContext'.
```

i can see the function in my ssdl file :

but no trace of it in object layer class...

Comment: it's not silly at all. Here's similar qustion about F# - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907198/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-postgresql-through-f-and-npgsql still unanswered. Looks like it not possible to called typed procedure, only some raw sql

Comment: well, that ..... big time, i think it is a problem of edmgen , the tool that maps the database